# Google chrome does not output anything after localhost

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, xampp

I am a noob trying to learn. I use Windows 7 32 bit and I downloaded and installed XAMPP. I created a folder named example in htdocs.  I saved my file test.php in this folder.  I launched GOOGLE CHROME and typed localhost/example/test and ENTER. I got the expected output (a string in test.php was displayed on the screen). Next, I created the myexample folder in htdocs and I saved mytest.php in this myexample Thfolder. I launched GOOGLECHROME and typed localhost/myexample/mytest.php and... I got no output. The file mytest.php is the same as the file test.php. What is going on?  As far as I can see, the only changes were the folder name and the file name. Why I am not getting the expected output displayed on the screen? I am asking for your help, please. Thank you

Comment: Did you try this using IE instead?  This seems like something rather unrelated to the use of Chrome

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Should be at `C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log` and `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`. That would be the first step. If it's not obvious, what the contents of those.

Comment: @Foon Not sure if you're serious with the suggestion of using IE.

Comment: Um... I hate IE at least as much as the next person, and if the OP was using a proper OS, I'd have suggested wget (since curl sometimes hides error messages without extra arguments), but the point is I rather doubt this is a browser issue and if I'm wrong, we've narrowed down the problem. Besides, the last time I helped someone with a browser question, IE was the easiest answer (the question was: how can see what the page looks like if my fonts are not loaded properly, and IE natively answered that just fine)

Comment: I chcked apache logs error

Comment: [Sat Aug 22 15:37:59.283196 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10128:tid 248] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Aug 23 12:26:31.627891 2015] [:error] [pid 10128:tid 1688] [client 127.0.0.1:9340] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/experiment/mytestingstring.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Aug 24 14:39:22.064863 2015] [:error] [pid 10128:tid 1692] [client 127.0.0.1:14504] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/myteststring.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: php logs error is empty